# which portion to read to be able to answer this question?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $l^2 = \{x = (x_n)| x_n \in \mathbb{R}, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n^2 < \infty\}$  be the Hilbert space of square summable sequences and let $e_k$ denote the $k^{th}$ co-ordinate vector (with $1$ in $k^{th}$ place, $0$ elsewhere). Which of the following subspaces is NOT dense in $l^2$?

1. span$\{e_1-e_2, e_2-e_3, \ldots\}$
2. span$\{2e_1-e_2, 2e_2-e_3, \ldots\}$
3. span$\{e_1-2e_2, e_2-2e_3, \ldots\}$
4. span$\{e_2, e_3, \ldots\}$

I have knowledge in Analysis , metric spaces , Topology. Still I find this problem   unacquainted. Can anyone please tell me which portion to read to be able to answer this question?

Comment: I suggest "A Hilbert Space Problem Book"  by Paul Halmos, which is an introductory textbook on Hilbert  space, in which the reader is asked to prove many of the theorems. (Solutions are given in the back of the book.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about Hilbert spaces. It should be covered in any Functional Analysis book.

That said, this concrete question only requires a bit of playing with bases and linear combinations, so it should not be that hard to anyone with a solid linear algebra background.

Comment: Can you please suggest me a good functional analysis  book? I have read Mukresh. and I love to read Mukresh.@Martin Argerami

Comment: With this concrete question I would recommend Conway's *A Course in Functional Analysis*. This one starts with Hilbert spaces in Chapter 1. Many others do first Banach spaces and only then Hilbert spaces.